# Pandastable Table not auto-scrolling down using down key

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am using pandastable to show data from my CSV to Tkinter GUI as a table structure. This table have vertical and horizontal scroll bars. Scroll bars work fine using mouse. When I press Down key, focus goes to next row. However, scroll bar does not work with Down Key. Is this feature not implemented in Pandastable or am I doing something wrong?

Example:

```
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table, TableModel

class TestApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        self.main.geometry('600x400+200+100')
        self.main.title('Table app')
        f = Frame(self.main)
        f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        df = TableModel.getSampleData()
        self.table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
        pt.show()
        return

app = TestApp()
#launch the app
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Fixed the indentation.

Comment: Have you tried [`bind`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an idea
in
../dist-packages/pandastable/core.py
in

```
 def handle_arrow_keys(self, event):


            if event.keysym == 'Up':
                if self.currentrow == 0:
                    return
                else:
                    #self.yview('moveto', y)
                    #self.rowheader.yview('moveto', y)
                    event.widget.config(yscrollincrement = self.rowheight) 
                    self.rowheader.config(yscrollincrement = self.rowheight)                 
                    self.currentrow  = self.currentrow -1
                    event.widget.yview_scroll(-1, UNITS)
                    self.rowheader.yview_scroll(-1, UNITS)
                    self.redrawVisible()
            elif event.keysym == 'Down':
                if self.currentrow >= self.rows-1:
                    return
                else:
                    #self.yview('moveto', y)
                    #self.rowheader.yview('moveto', y)
                    event.widget.config(yscrollincrement = self.rowheight)
                    self.rowheader.config(yscrollincrement = self.rowheight)                                                  
                    self.currentrow  = self.currentrow +1
                    event.widget.yview_scroll(1, UNITS)
                    self.rowheader.yview_scroll(1, UNITS)
                    self.redrawVisible()
```

scroll only one line:  `.config(yscrollincrement = self.rowheight)`
from

```
def mouse_wheel(self, event):

    event.widget.yview_scroll(-1, UNITS)
    self.rowheader.yview_scroll(-1, UNITS)
    self.redrawVisible()
```